# How to convert one reflect.Type to its ptr type?

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, types

I have one reflect.Type and I need to call `MethodByName`. If the method is defined on type `T`, no problem to find it. If it's defined on `*T`, this mehtod will return invalid value. So I tried to convert `T` to `*T` and failed. Here is what I do:

First, I tried to create a new value from the type. Type infomation seems to lost after creation.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(src) // src is interface{} type
mt, exists := t.MethodByName(name)
if !exists {
    el := reflect.New(t)
    t = reflect.TypeOf(el)
    mt, exists = t.MethodByName(name)
    fmt.Println(t, mt, exists)
}
```

Then, I tried to get type directly from src(the interface type), and failed   also.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(src)
mt, exists := t.MethodByName(name)
if !exists {
    t = reflect.TypeOf(&src) // *interface{} type, not what I want
    mt, exists = t.MethodByName(name)
    fmt.Println(t, mt, exists)
}
```

Comment: New returns a reflect.Value, calling TypeOf with it as its argument will return the reflect.Type of the reflect.Value type. reflect.Value has a method Type, try that. i.e. `reflect.New(t).Type()` instead of `reflect.TypeOf(reflect.New(t))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) returns a value of type [`reflect.Value()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). If you pass this to [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf), that will be the descriptor of `reflect.Value`, not your `*T`.

Simply call [`Value.Type()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Type) from the value returned by `reflect.New()`:

```
el := reflect.New(t)
t = el.Type()
mt, exists = t.MethodByName(name)
fmt.Println(t, mt, exists)
```